# Im wondering how I would be able to get a discord bot to randomly ping someone from the guild its in with discord.js

Tags: random, discord.js

I have this

```
    }else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}command`) {
    message.delete()
    const randomuser = Array.from(message.member.guild.members)
    randomperson = (math.random() *0 + guild.membercount)
    message.channel.send([randomuser])
  .then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 100 })
  })
```

but using it results with this

```
    message.channel.send([Array.from(message.member.guild.members())])
    TypeError: message.member.guild.members is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mrcoo\Desktop\Discord Bots\WeeWeeBot\WeeWeeBot\index.js:59:59)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\mrcoo\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

I want to make it get an array of users from the guild that the message was sent in and then randomly choose one using the amount of users in the guild and all the tutorials I've found are for v11.5.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `message.guild.members.cache`:

```js
    }else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}command`) {
    message.delete()
    const randomuser = message.guild.members.cache.array();
    randomperson = (math.random() *0 + guild.membercount)
    message.channel.send([randomuser])
  .then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 100 })
  })
```

`message.guild.members` is a `GuildMemberManager` and can't be converted to an array of `Member`.

Comment: How would i choose someone random out of the members array?

Answer (score 0):

```
}else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}command`) {
            message.delete()
            const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
            var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount)
            var pingPerson = userList[randomNumber] 
            message.channel.send("<@" + pingPerson.user.id + ">")
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 0 })
  
  })
```